# How can I automatically rotate/archive my bash history logs?

Tags: bash-history

I know that Bash has both `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` variables that control how long history is saved for, and how much of it is saved.  I would like to keep an archive of my history.  However, if I set either of the two variables mentioned above to a very large number, it makes searching for old commands very difficult, and after enough time they might get deleted anyway.

How can I automatically archive my bash history files once they get to a certain size, and is this method applicable to other log files (such as `/var/log/auth.log`)?

Answer (score 8):

```
#!/bin/sh
# This script creates monthly backups of the bash history file. Make sure you have
# HISTSIZE set to large number (more than number of commands you can type in every
# month). It keeps last 200 commands when it "rotates" history file every month.
# Typical usage in a bash profile:
#
# HISTSIZE=90000
# source ~/bin/history-backup
#
# And to search whole history use:
# grep xyz -h --color ~/.bash_history.*
#

KEEP=200
BASH_HIST=~/.bash_history
BACKUP=$BASH_HIST.$(date +%y%m)

if [ -s "$BASH_HIST" -a "$BASH_HIST" -nt "$BACKUP" ]; then
  # history file is newer then backup
  if [[ -f $BACKUP ]]; then
    # there is already a backup
    cp -f $BASH_HIST $BACKUP
  else
    # create new backup, leave last few commands and reinitialize
    mv -f $BASH_HIST $BACKUP
    tail -n$KEEP $BACKUP > $BASH_HIST
    history -r
  fi
fi
```

Taken from [Never lost your bash history again](http://lukas.zapletalovi.com/2013/03/never-lost-your-bash-history-again.html) on  "https://lukas.zapletalovi.com".

Answer (score 5):

You can use logrotate to backup your `~/.bash_history` file.

Create a config file for logrotate in `/etc/logrotate.d/bash_history`.

```
/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.bash_history {
    weekly
    missingok
    rotate 5
    size 5000k
    nomail
    notifempty
    create 600 YOUR_USERNAME YOUR_USERNAME
}
```

You can check if it works using this command:

```bsh
sudo logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/bash_history
```

To see the files:

```bsh
ls ~/.bash_history*
```

I found it on this webpage
https://kowalcj0.github.io/2019/05/13/logrotate-bash-history/

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question first:

The Ubuntu log files are *already* processed by `logrotate` to keep them managable and within size limits.

You can possibly even "abuse" it for your history files, it is quite convenient.

Answer (score 2):

This solution saves with date-time of execution:

```
mkdir ~/.logs
```

add this to your .bashrc or .bash_profile:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]; then echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S") $(pwd) $(history 1)" >> ~/.logs/bash-history-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d").log; fi'
```

to search in history type:

```
grep -h logcat ~/.logs/bash-history-2016-04*
```

taken from https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/05/28/log-bash-history/

Comment: What if `PROMPT_COMMAND` already contains something? Wouldn't it be safer to concatenate your command with it instead? Maybe something like `export PROMPT_COMMAND=$"$PROMPT_COMMAND\n <your code>"` would do.

Comment: my PROMPT_COMMAND already had something. so I assigned it to a variable prompt_command and after export command, I do `export PROMPT_COMMAND="prompt_command;$PROMPT_COMMAND"`

Comment: I like the possibility of saving directory and time date also